# How to compare two identical tables for matching or not matching rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to compare two tables for each matching or not matching rows. 
  I have a table like below where each row is a configuration for a device and i need to compare this with another same table and find which rows are not matching there

```
PID DEVID  INID EVTYPEID EVID   ALID    PARMID TEXTID
1   20      0     30      0    100102      0    14
1   103     0     30      0    100103      0    15              
9   21      0     30      0    100113      0    25
0   31      2     30      0    100114      0    26
8   38     18     4      53    100114      0    0
4   20     17     4      53    1000114     0    0
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the issue you are having? You need to decide how to join the tables, then INNER JOIN will give you matching records, and a LEFT JOIN and WHERE [joining column] IS NULL will give you records that are not in the other table.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Seems like a very simple query to me: Join both tables on the ID columns and compare the other columns if they match or don't match.

Comment: @Leonidas199x , l cant make left join work out here. somehow  i am not getting it

Comment: @coffemug if you need a hand, post up your code. Is the table structure for both tables exactly the same?

Comment: @waka .do i need to  join all the columns with each other.  `a.pid=b.pid and a.devod.b.pid.....................`

Comment: @coffemug No - just the column(s) that ensure the join is joining to the correct record.

Comment: @Leonidas199x . .yes.. exactly the same

Answer (score 2):

You can use `except`. You might want to specify the table columns to make sure they are in the correct order.

```
select *
from tbl1

except 

select *
from tbl2
```

And for matching rows you can use `intersect`

Comment: Was about to post the same thing. For the record here is the documentation on EXCEPT. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql

Comment: I always forget about `Except`. Think of it as a `Left Union`. :-)

Comment: it returned 181 records .

Comment: @coffemug That does not mean anything to me. Good, bad?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` or `not exists` or `in` and `not in` for comparing values between tables.

```
    Select PID, DEVID, INID, EVTYPEID,EVID   ALID,PARMID,TEXTID from tableA as A 
where exists (select 1 from tableB as B where a.PID=b.PID and a.DEVID=b.DEVID...) - -  you can add as per ur requirement)
```

Comment: select 1 ,  what does it mean

Comment: @coffemug if you get any matching record from subquery we can return some value like 1 or any column value so that from main table will get corresponding matched record.